# What is the structural difference between MQ sensors?

Tags: sensor

What is the difference between MQ-8 and MQ-136 structurally?

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange.  Please take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  While those sensors can be used by Arduino this is not an Arduino-based question, and will likely be moved to Electrical Engineering SE...  In any case, this article gives a little detail responsive to your question:  https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MQGasSensorshttps://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MQGasSensors

Answer (score 0):

[MQ8 datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-8.pdf), according datasheet:

- High sensitivity to Hydrogen (H2)
- Small sensitivity to alcohol, LPG,cooking fumes

[MQ136 datasheet](http://www.china-total.com/Product/meter/gas-sensor/MQ136.pdf) This sensor is for sulfur dioxide

Comment: I suspect the user wishes to know how they're internally different.